# Converting an node js app to android app

Tags: node.js

I have developed a web app in node js using express which also involves mongodb. How to convert it to an android app ? 
My main app file is directly inside the main application folder.

Answer (score 4):

Your subject in this thread looks confuse. I think that you want to convert web application (can be express.js app, php app, or jsp, etc) into mobile application (ios or android).

If it is so, you can use `cordova` to do it.

Please read this document.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide/cli/index.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, this will only work for 'frontend-only' apps which can be served from a static file server. I haven't been able to find anything in the cordova docs which would let you package a node module or mongo database along with your app.